# Using Pandoc with vim keybindings

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, autocmd, filetype

I am trying to define a keymapping in `vimrc` to compile my markdown file with Pandoc.
So I am using this:

```
autocmd FileType markdown nmap <F9> :!pandoc % -o %:r.pdf <cr>
```

But, in markdown file when I am pressing F9 nothing is happening.
I am not sure if this is the line I need to add in my `vimrc` file. Right now I don't want to install any plugins like `vim-pandoc` or something like that.

Comment: You may need the `:S` filename modifier, to prevent some special characters in the filename to interfere. Do one of these work?: `autocmd FileType markdown nnoremap <F9> :<c-u>!pandoc %:p:S -o %:p:r:S.pdf<cr>`, or `autocmd FileType markdown nnoremap <F9> :<c-u>sil call system('pandoc '.expand('%:p:S').' -o '.expand('%:p:r:S').'.pdf')<cr>`

Comment: yes!, I checked both and it works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: To create your mapping properly you really should add `<buffer>` to your mapping command (see [`:h :map-<buffer>`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3amap-%3cbuffer%3e)) this way your mapping will only exist in the appropriate buffers (with the markdown filetype). You also should read [`:h ftplugin`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_41.txt.html#ftplugin): don't use an autocommand to create the mapping, use a ftplugin, they are made for that :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your mapping has a few issues:

```
autocmd FileType markdown nmap <F9> :!pandoc % -o %:r.pdf <cr>
```

You use a recursive command `:nmap`, but you don't need recursiveness, so you should [prefer `:nnoremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html):

```
autocmd FileType markdown nnoremap <F9> :!pandoc % -o %:r.pdf <cr>
                          ^^^^^^^^
```

---

There's an unneeded space at the end:

```
autocmd FileType markdown nnoremap <F9> :!pandoc % -o %:r.pdf <cr>
                                                             ^
```

---

You use the `:!` bang command, without prefixing it with the keycode `<c-u>` (see `:h c^u`).
As a result, if you press a count before `<F9>`, it will be automatically translated into a range.
And a range before `:!` means that Vim will filter some lines in your buffer (see `:h :range!`), which you probably don't want here.

```
autocmd FileType markdown nnoremap <F9> :<c-u>!pandoc % -o %:r.pdf<cr>
                                         ^^^^^
```

---

Your filename may contain some special characters which are automatically expanded on Vim's (see `:h cmdline-special`) or the shell's command-line.

To prevent Vim and the shell from interpreting them, you could use the `:S` filename modifier (see `:h filename-modifiers`), and just to be safe you could also add the `:p` modifier so that the paths passed to `$ pandoc` are absolute:

```
autocmd FileType markdown nnoremap <F9> :<c-u>!pandoc %:p:S -o %:p:r:S.pdf<cr>
                                                       ^^^^     ^^  ^^
```

Note that if you use multiple filename modifiers, `:S` must be the last one.

---

`:!` is good for an interactive use, but usually in a script you use `system()`.

```
autocmd FileType markdown nnoremap <F9> :<c-u>silent call system('pandoc '.expand('%:p:S').' -o '.expand('%:p:r:S').'.pdf')<cr>
```

In this form, Vim doesn't expand the special character `%` so you have to invoke `expand()` (see `:h expand()`).
The purpose of `:silent` is to avoid stray characters showing up on your screen (see `:h system()`):

> When prepended by |:silent| the terminal will not be set to
>   cooked mode.  This is meant to be used for commands that do
>   not need the user to type.  It avoids stray characters showing
>   up on the screen which require |CTRL-L| to remove.

---

You should wrap your autocmds into a self-clearing augroup so that they aren't duplicated if you resource your `vimrc` (see `:h autocmd-remove`):

```
augroup my_markdown
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType markdown nnoremap <F9> :<c-u>silent call system('pandoc '.expand('%:p:S').' -o '.expand('%:p:r:S').'.pdf')<cr>
augroup END
```

---

As [@statox explained](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/17549/using-pandoc-with-vim-keybindings#comment30069_17549), your mapping is global, but you probably want it only in a markdown buffer, so you should pass the `<buffer>` argument to `:nnoremap`.

Also, autocmds in your `vimrc` don't scale well passed a certain point, so you could use a filetype plugin.
For markdown, you could use the file `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/markdown.vim`.

Note that by using a filetype plugin you don't need an autocmd anymore.

And in addition to `<buffer>`, you probably want to pass the arguments `<nowait>` and `<silent>` to `:nnoremap`.

```
nnoremap <buffer><nowait><silent> <F9> :<c-u>silent call system('pandoc '.expand('%:p:S').' -o '.expand('%:p:r:S').'.pdf')<cr>
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

`<silent>` is to prevent Vim from displaying the `rhs` of your mapping on the command-line when you press `F9`.
`<nowait>` is to prevent Vim from waiting a few seconds if another mapping begin with `F9`.
Usually, when that happens, it's a conflict between a local and global mapping, and you probably want to give the priority to the local one.

---

In your filetype plugin, you could tell Vim to remove the mapping if you change the filetype of your buffer by including a `:nunmap` command in the buffer-local variable `b:undo_ftplugin` (see `:h undo_ftplugin`):

```
let b:undo_ftplugin = get(b:, 'undo_ftplugin', '')
    \ . (empty(get(b:, 'undo_ftplugin', '')) ? '' : '|')
    \ . "
    \       exe 'nunmap <buffer> <F9>'
    \ "
```

Comment: Just to add to this great answer: the last step to really improve this mapping is to get rid of it. First define the `makeprg` to use pandoc properly for markdown and then optionnally create a mapping which calls `make` (this mapping could be global since `makeprg` should be changed for each filetype. ([`:h 'makeprg'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27makeprg%27))

Comment: Note that repeated string concatenation can be made a little clearer with `printf` (it may be `sprintf`—one of these should return a string).